# Php mail array to string

Tags: php, email

I need to send an email to users , everyone . and this is the array

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { ["email"]=> string(20) "test@outlook.fr" ["name"]=> string(8) "حمزة" } 
    [1]=> array(2) { ["email"]=> string(13) "test@yahoo.com" ["name"]=> string(4) "tooo" } 
    [2]=> array(2) { ["email"]=> string(14) "test@inbox.ru" ["name"]=> string(8) "احمد" } 
    [3]=> array(2) { ["email"]=> string(21) "test@gmail.com" ["name"]=> string(14) "اشهارات" } 
    [4]=> array(2) { ["email"]=> string(20) "test@yahoo.com" ["name"]=> string(9)
```

and I have this code to send email

```
$hs = "From: \"Ishharat\"<moi@test.com>\n";
$hs .= "Reply-To: moi@test.com\n";
$hs .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";

 if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$hs))
   return TRUE;
 else {
   return FALSE;
 }
```

Comment: create email method and use it in loop on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a foreach loop;

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user->email; // the email to use in the mail() function
  $user->name; // The name to use in the headers of the mail() function
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir , It's working but I have used $user["email"]